# How to display form output in the same window and hide the form as well

Tags: javascript, html, forms, output, action

I have been beating my head on it since yesterday but to no avail. What I need to do is make a form and display custom greeting cards. We are allowed to use pictures as cards (set them as background for the output). The form should let the user enter some customization information such the name of the recipient, colour information, font sizes and other information as you see fit. There should be a "make card" button that, when they hit it, hides the form (by changing the CSS visibility or display property of the corresponding element) and shows a card, with a simple but elegant design that incorporates the text they and other configuration details they entered.

Also I need to have the background picture as per their selection in the type of greeting card and have a small sticker size picture on the card for the characters they choose.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Following is my Java Script CSS and HTML code:

```js
< script >
  function selectAll() {
    for (i = 0; i < document.forms[0]['charac'].length - 1; i++)
      document.forms[0]['charac'][i].checked = document.forms[0]['charac'][5].checked;
  }
document.forms[0]['charac'][5].addEventListener('click', selectAll);

function myCard() {

  document.getElementById("formOutput").style.backgroundImage = "url('birthday-card.jpg')";

  var selected;
  if (selected == document.forms[0]['card'][0]) {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('birthday-card.jpg')";
    document.getElementById("formOutput").innerHTML = "name";
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  var a = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("txtName1").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("content-field").value;

  document.getElementById("formOutput").innerHTML = a + " " + b + " " + c;
} < /script>
```

```css
<style> #wrapper {
  border: 3px black;
}
body {
  background-image: url("blank-card1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  /*             background-image: image("blank-card.jpg");*/
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
table td {
  height: 15px;
  /*            width: 15px;*/
  text-align: left;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Generate a Greeting Card</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Fill out the following information and select a card to view how it looks.</h3>
  <form id="formCard" action="">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Personal information:</legend>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="txtName">Your Name<span style="color:red">*</span>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtName" name="name" value=" " required/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="txtName1">Your Family Member's
              <br>OR Friend's Name<span style="color:red">*</span>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtName1" name="name1" value=" " required/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="txtAddress">Address</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtAddress" name="address" value=" ">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="postalCode">Postal Code<span style="color:red">*</span>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="postalCode" name="postalcode" value=" " required/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Province<span style="color:red">*</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select id="selProvince" name="province" required>
              <option value="" selected>Please select...</option>
              <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
              <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
              <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
              <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
              <option value="NFL">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
              <option value="NW">Northwest Territories</option>
              <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
              <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
              <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
              <option value="PEI">Prince Edward Island</option>
              <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
              <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
              <option value="YK">Yukon</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="txtPhone">Phone<span style="color:red">*</span>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtPhone" name="phone" value=" " required/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="txtEmail">Email<span style="color:red">*</span>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtEmail" name="email" required/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Would you like to send it
            <br>via email or mail<span style="color:red" required>*</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="route" value="m" />Mail</label>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="route" value="e" />Email</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Type of Greeting Card:<span style="color:red">*</span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
          </td>
          <td>
            <br>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="card" id="birthday" value="bd" />Birthday</label>
            <br>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="card" id="valentine" value="vd" />Valentines Day</label>
            <br>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="card" id="friendship" value="frd" />Friendship Day</label>
            <br>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="card" id="mother" value="md" />Mother's Day</label>
            <br>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="card" id="father" value="fad" />Father's Day</label>
            <br>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="card" id="newYear" value="nyd" />New Year's Day</label>
            <br>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="card" id="christmas" value="cd" />Christmas Day</label>
            <br>
            <br>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Choose the person's
            <br>Favourite cartoon charcters:<span style="color:red">*</span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="charac" value="mickeyMouse" checked/>Mickey Mouse &amp; Clubhouse</label>
            <br>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="charac" value="scoobyDoo" />Scooby Doo</label>
            <br>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="charac" value="tomJerry" />Tom &amp; Jerry</label>
            <br>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="charac" value="tweetiePie" />Tweetie Pie</label>
            <br>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="charac" value="donaldDuck" />Donald Duck</label>
            <br>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="charac" value="selectAll" />Select All</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Choose a colour for the
            <br>text on the card:</td>
          <!--color code from w3schools.org-->
          <td>
            <input type="color" id="html5colorpicker" onchange="clickColor(0, -1, -1, 5)" value="#ff0000" style="width:85%;">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>Content</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <textarea id="content-field" cols="20" rows="2" value=" "></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Choose an image to put on
            <br>the card to make it special.</td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
            </label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input onclick="myFucntion()" type="submit" value="SEND" />&nbsp;
            <input type="reset" value="CLEAR" />
          </td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <p><span id="formOutput"></span>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is the SEND button the equivalent of the "make card" button that you talk about in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this:

```
<form ...>
    <fieldset id='fields'>
        ...
        <input onclick="showOutput()" type="submit" value="SEND" />
    </fieldset>
    <div id='formOutput' style='display: none;'>
    </div>
</form>

function showOutput() {
    /* Fill formOutput */
    ....
    document.getElementById('fields').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('formOutput).style.display = '';
}
```

But since the SEND button is a submit button, I don't know if you want to do all the processing in the Javascript code.

Also, if you want to allow toggling between the two views, the "toggle" button would have to be outside of the fieldset (or a button would be needed inside of formOutput to go back to the input view).

Comment: Also I need to have the background picture as per their selection in the type of greeting card and have a small sticker size picture on the card for the characters they choose.